# Constructor and using methods

Tags: python, methods

I have created the following constructor:

```
class Analysis:

    def __init__(self, file_list, tot_col, tot_rows):
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.tot_col = tot_col
        self.tot_rows = tot_rows
```

I then have the method `full_analysis()` call `calc_total_rows()` from the same file:

```
def full_analysis(self):
        """Currently runs all the analysis methods"""
        print('Analysing file...\n' +
              '----------------------------\n')
        calc_total_rows()
```

From another file I am calling the `full_analysis()` however errors occur saying that `calc_total_rows()` is not defined, and the method is just below it.
I'm inexperienced with Python however I tried to rearrange the code and add 'self' in various places to no avail.

The other file does meet the requirements of the constructor, and if I remove the `calc_total_rows()` method, the print line runs. I however do not wish to call each method individually, and would like to call a single method which runs them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `calc_total_rows` is an instance method as your question implies, then you need to call `self.calc_total_rows()` from within `full_analysis`.  Unlike some other languages, Python does not have implicit instance references within method scope; you have to explicitly retrieve the member method from `self`.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had found this sooner.

In order to solve this, I had to use **self** in front of the method.

In my example:

```
def full_analysis(self):
        """Currently runs all the analysis methods"""
        print('Analysing file...\n' +
              '----------------------------\n')
        self.calc_total_rows()
```

This works.